# Customizing authorstyle citation and numbered bibliography in different Format using Biblateex

Tags: biblatex

I need authoryear e.g (Ning and Lovell, 2002) and numbered bibliography as under using Biblatex

Kindly Suggest to edit modification to standard.bbx to generate bibliography as:

> [1] Ning, X., and Lovell, M. R., (2002), "On the Sliding Friction Characteristics of Unidirectional Continuous FRP Composites", ASME J. Tribol., 124(1), pp. 5-13.
>
> [2] Barnes, M., (2001), "Stresses in Solenoids", J. Appl. Phys., 48(5), pp. 2000–2008.
>
> [3] Jones, J., (2000), Contact Mechanics, Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, UK, Chap. 6.
>
> [4] Lee, Y., Korpela, S. A., and Horne, R. N., (1982), "Structure of Multi-Cellular Natural Convection in a Tall Vertical Annulus", Proc. 7th International Heat Transfer Conference, U. Grigul et al., eds., Hemisphere, Washington, DC, 2, pp. 221–226.
>
> [5] Watson, D. W., (1997), "Thermodynamic Analysis", ASME Paper No. 97-GT-288.
>
> [6] Tung, C. Y., (1982), "Evaporative Heat Transfer in the Contact Line of a Mixture", Ph.D. thesis, Rensselaer Polytechnic Institute, Troy, NY.
>
> [7] Smith, R., (2002), "Conformal Lubricated Contact of Cylindrical Surfaces Involved in a Non-Steady Motion", from web site http://www.cas.phys.unm.edu/rsmith/homepage.html accessed on 12/08/2007.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Does it really make sense to number the bibliography when you cite as in a `authoryear` style? Can you also explain what exactly you want changed is it only that you want an `authoryear` style that is also numbered (do you want the `numbering` to be usable as citations as well?). Also please post a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) so we have something to go by and play with.

Comment: I know the question i am asking is not as per standardized styles followed i.e. if citation is authoryear then bibliography should not be numbered. But I am preparing a template for a university which has this problematic style i.e. cite style and bib style are different. So I need your help to create a <newstyle.bbx>. The required output is shown in the aboove question.

Comment: I found two solutions. First is to customize biblatex.cfg and second is to create new .bbx file with cutomized style.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't make much sense to me, but you can use different `citestyle` and `bibstyle` with `biblatex`.

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[backend=biber,citestyle=authoryear,bibstyle=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}

\cite{angenendt}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]